# Swift 3.1 - .setValuesForKeys and Firebase failing to retrive users

Tags: swift, firebase, set, key

So I have this piece of code that is suppose to fetch users from the database and store them in an Array (drivingUsers). I get no errors but when I run the app it crashes.

```
 func fetchUser() {
    FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("user_profiles").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
           let user = User()


            user.setValuesForKeys(dictionary) //Error


            self.drivingUsers.append(user)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }, withCancel: nil)


}
```

Error Log:

```
 2017-04-29 00:41:46.842568 VEXI[1745:369755] -[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x174a34500
 2017-04-29 00:41:46.844084 VEXI[1745:369755] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x174a34500'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error `unrecognized selector sent to instance` means you tried to set a key to a value of the wrong type. It's not clear from your code what kind of object `User` is, or what keys are in the `dictionary` object, but one of the values is not the type that `User` is expecting for that key.

To fix it, you'll need to cast each value in the dictionary to the right type.

Answer (score 1):

... I fixed it.

Replacing

```
user.setValuesForKeys(dictionary)
```

with

```
user.name = dictionary["name"] as? String
user.email = dictionary["email"] as? String
user.picture = dictionary["picture"] as? String
user.facebookID = dictionary["facebookID"] as? String
user.status = dictionary["status"] as? String
user.date_joined = dictionary["date_joined"] as? String
user.last_login = dictionary["last_login"] as? String
user.Longitude = dictionary["Longitude"] as? String
user.Latitude = dictionary["Latitude"] as? String
```